# Grant access to Joomla API from just one site

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-api, restful-api, header, joomla-5.x

In Joomla Joomla 4/5:

What is the best strategy to allow access to Joomla API endpoints from only one (or more) specific domains?
And how is this configured in Joomla 4/5? (CORS vs. HTTP-Header-Plugin vs. other solution).

I simply cannot find a best practice by checking the documentation on this topic.